# Problems calculating performance and plotting LSTM predictions

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have fitted a neural network on stock data as follows. First I downloaded the required data and made some slight changes to obtain a univariate dataset:

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf    
df=yf.download('^GSPC', period='20y', progress=False) 
df=df.drop(df.columns[0:5], axis=1)
```

Then I split the data into training and test sets:

```
df=df.astype(float)
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
test_size = len(df) - train_size
df_train, df_test = df[0:train_size], df[train_size:len(df)]
```

and normalised both:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler    
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
df_train_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(df_train)
df_test_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(df_test)
```

Now, to the crucial part. First, I used a handy function to reshape the input data as required by keras:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from numpy import array
def data_preparation_univariate(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        end_ix = i + n_steps
        if end_ix > len(sequence)-1:
            break
        seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    return array(X), array(y)
n_steps=10
X_train, y_train = data_preparation_univariate(df_train_scaled, n_steps)
X_test, y_test = data_preparation_univariate(df_test_scaled, n_steps)
features = 1
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], features))
X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], features))
```

Then I defined the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

Then I fit the model on the training data

```
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=20, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2)
```

and on test data:

```
predict_test=model.predict(X_test,verbose=2)
```

Finally I scaled back predictions and actual values:

```
y_test = scaler.inverse_transform(y_test)
predict_test=scaler.inverse_transform(forecast_test)
```

At this point, however, when I call `predict_test.shape`, I get a 2-d array of length `(998, 10)` as expected from the required transformations, and when I call `y_test.shape` I get a  2-d array of length `(998,1)`. When I try to compute the mean squared error of the predictions as:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mse=mean_squared_error(y_test,predict_test)
```

I get the error `ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=10)` since of course the array dimensions are different. Moreover, when I plot the two series against each other:

```
plt.plot(y_test, label='Actual')
plt.plot(forecast_test, label='Predicted')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

the graph clearly shows that there are 10 series of predicted values. Hence my question is: how can I reshape my data back to the original format, so that I can plot the two series one against the other and I can compute some accuracy metrics?

P.S. If you find mistakes in my procedure feel free to point them out. I am still new to LSTMs and keras and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output layer of the network has a bad shape (10) but the output value is suppose to be just one. So changing the line

`model.add(Dense(X_train.shape[1]))`

into

`model.add(Dense(1))`

solves the problem.

P.S. looking at the input data, the dates are not strictly consecutive:

```
2001-10-04  1.609100e+09
2001-10-05  1.301700e+09
2001-10-08  9.790000e+08
```

however, you treat them as if they are. I recommend here filling the sequence with interpolated numbers to make better predictions.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue! On your second point, yes dates are not consecutive since only trading days are recorded and no measurements exist on non-trading days. Therefore I am not sure that adding extra days is a sound strategy (theory-wise) but I will try it and see if it improves performance

Comment: Ok, now I understand, those are weekends&holidays missing. Then it's perfectly fine to leave it like that.